# Apply AcousticEchoCanceler on android SIPDemo?

Tags: android, sip, audiorecord

I used sample Android code(SipDemo) to implement simple SIP client, but noticed strong echo while calling.

I found Android the class AcousticEchoCanceler that can reduce echo effect but i don't know where can I get AudioSessionId.

Is there a possibility to get the audiosessionid of de AudioRecord object on the SipDemo?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Your session ID is associated with the variable you used for AudioRecord.  In this case, I called mine "AudioRecord recorder".  However, I have not gotten it to work with my Galaxy S5.  It doesn't seem to do anything, despite saying it's enabled, and available.

```
aec = AcousticEchoCanceler.create(recorder.getAudioSessionId());
```